# Question regarding the skorokhod representation of a random variable with prescribed distribution function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $F$ is a cdf, i.e., it satisfies:

1. F is non-decreasing ($x\leq y \implies F(x) \leq F(y)$).
2. $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} F(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} F(x) = 0$.
3. F is right continuous.

The goal is to show that
$$
\inf\{z: F(z) > w\} = \sup\{z: F(z) \leq w\}
$$

I have tried my hand but can't seem to to do a clean proof.

**Edit: My tries:**

Define the sets $S_1 = \{z: F(z) > w\}$ and $S_2 = \{y: F(y) \leq w\}$. Then it is clear that since $F$ is non-decreasing we have for $z_1 \in S_1$ and $z_2 \in S_2$, $z_2 \leq z_1$ leading to the fact that:
$$
\sup S_2 \leq \inf S_1
$$
What is left is to prove the reverse inequality and we are done. To this end, we have to use the fact $F$ is right continuous somehow. To that end the fact that $F$ is also monotone renders it to have countable discontinuities, in fact finite number of them in any open interval sine it is right continuous. So given any $a$ we can have an open interval around it such that $F$ is discontinuous at most on $a$ it self. In that case:
$$
\lim_{z \rightarrow a^+} F(z) = F(a) \implies  a = \inf S_1$$
the only problem now is to prove that this infimum is less than or equal to $\sup S2$.

Comment: What have you tries ? where are you stuck ? [How to ask a good question ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that only the first condition is useful here.

---

Let $i=\inf\{z\mid F(z)>w\}$ and $s=\sup\{z\mid F(z)\leq w\}$.

- Then, there are $(i_n)$ and $(s_n)$ s.t. $i_n\searrow i$ and $s_n\nearrow s$ s.t. $$F(s_n)\leq w\quad \text{and}\quad F(i_n)>w.$$ Since $F$ is non-decreasing, we have that $s_n\leq i_n$ for all $n$, and thus $s\leq i$.
- Suppose $s<i$, and let $u\in (s,i)$. Then either $F(u)\leq w$ which contradict $s=\sup\{z\mid F(z)\leq w\}$ or $F(u)>w$ which contradict $i=\inf\{z\mid F(z)>w\}$.

Therefore $s=i$.